# How to reduce location update interval when user is not moving?

Tags: android, rx-java, android-location

I have an app which is specifically for location tracking of a fleet of vehicles.
I am using `ReactiveLocationProvider` for this. Following is the code which creates the `LocationRequest`.

```
mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();     
mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(10000);
mLocationRequest.setInterval(10 * 1000); // Update location every 10 seconds

mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(30.0f); // Call location updates only after 30mts
```

The problem with above code is that when vehicle stops the location update will also stop for that duration and if I remove the distance constraint i.e. `mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(30.0f)`, the update interval will still be 10 seconds which is redundant for a stopped vehicle.

Is there a way where I can set the location update interval of a stopped vehicle to a larger value than my default value?

EDIT1:

Is `mLocationRequest.setMaxWaitTime()` something which I need?

c.f. https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest.html#setMaxWaitTime(long)